# Co-efficient of $x^{12}$ in the given Power Series

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Qyestion 
Find Coefficient of $x^{12}$ in $${(x*\frac{\left(1-x^6\right)}{(1-x)})}^3$$

My attempt (using Generator Functions)

Since we know that,
$$\frac{\left(1-x^6\right)}{(1-x)} = \left(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\right)$$

therefore the given problem reduces to finding the co-efficient of $x^{12}$ in

$(x*\left(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\right))^3$,

taking that $x^{3}$ out, that means we need to find the co-efficient of $x^{9}$ 
in

$\left(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\right)^3$,

which in turn is equivalent to $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+2}{2}x^{m}$, the coefficient of 
$x^{9}$ will be $\binom{11}{2}. $ i.e $55$

(i haven't shifted the series to match the correct order though but it isn't necessary right as that is a variable change i.e substituing $m+2 = r$)

but the (book's) answer says the co-efficient isn't that, rather it's 25.

Where did i go wrong in applying the logic?

Thanks a lot for your time.

(I did check other amazing answers here, they all seem to suggest to do  simplification, so I also did but don't know what went wrong. :( )

Here's what the **Book's** explanation says which i understand very well but what's **wrong** with the above said approach is what I am trying to understand,

[image: book's desc]

Comment: "$\left(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\right)^3$, which in turn is equivalent to $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\binom{m+2}{2}x^{m}$" Well, no, what makes you think they are equivalent?

Comment: Hmm, thanks @Did, I understood my mistake, I can't do that as it isn't correct since we have that exponent there and terms before were finite but with this change they become infinite summation, right?

Comment: Indeed you are dealing with a polynomial (of degree 15), hence it cannot coincide with the series.

Comment: Thanks a lot again :)